# how to pass database value to html input type in php like autocompet

Tags: php, jquery

I have working on core php,i need database values pass to input type fields like autocomplete, i'm getting database value from database,please help any one i tried long time but i'm not getting.

mysql code:

```
<?php

include('db_connection.php');
$list = array();
$sql = "SELECT `name` FROM `tbl_master_property`";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $list[] = $row;
}
$pr = json_encode($list);
?>
```

Html code:

```
 <div class="search">
    <label>PG Name</label>
    <input class="border col-lg-12" type="text" name="name" required="required" class="searchTerm" />
    <button type="submit" id ="submit" class="searchButton">
        <i class="fa fa-search searchButtonSearch"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your jquery?

Comment: for autocomplete use autocomplete jquery library

Comment: Complete example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48634888/display-unlisted-auto-complete-search-results-with-php/48638118#48638118

Comment: please refer https://referencekiru.wordpress.com/portfolio/projects/

Answer (score 0):

It's easy by using jQuery. If you get values from your db by using AJAX call, then simply on `success` callback try to use something like this:

```
if(response.name) {
  $("input[name='name']").value(response.name);
}
```

And so on

Comment: Hi JavaEvgen,I tried but i'm not getting this is my mysql query please check it once:

Comment: if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
    //get search term
    $searchTerm = isset($_GET['term']) ? '%'.$_GET['term'].'%' : null;

    //get matched data from name table
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT `name` FROM `tbl_master_property`");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $searchTerm);

    $result = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $data[] = [
           
            'label' => $row['name'],    
            
    }
    $response($data);
}