# How to fetch data from MySQL database and use in a javascript autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I'm building an autocomplete with [jQuery autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). To accomplish this I have stored 216 data records of industries in a table. I would like to fetch that table and use in javascript array for the autocomplete. You can see what I have tried so far but I'm getting null. My question is how do I fetch the data from the database and make it an array I can use in a javascript array for the autocomplete?

**table**

```
id | industryName
1  | Air Transport
2  | Agriculture
...
```

**autocomplete.php**

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="industries">Industries: </label>
  <input id="industries">
</div>

<script>
        $.ajax({
           url : 'industries.php',
           type : 'GET',
           success : function(data){
              var availableIndustries = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        $( function() {
        $( "#industries" ).autocomplete({
          source: availableIndustries
        });
      } );
           }
        });
</script>
```

**industries.php**

```
include 'includes/database.php';

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM industries";
 $result= $conn->query($sql);
 echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Did you remember to actually include both jQuery and jQueryUI?

Comment: Should be `source: 'industries.php'`, [here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48634888/display-unlisted-auto-complete-search-results-with-php/48638118#48638118)

Comment: @Richard : This is what I see when I run  `industries.php ` :  `{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null} `

Comment: @ObsidianAge: Just verified and yes everything is there. I'm using jquery on a different page for calendar and it works fine.

Comment: @JavaNoob are you sure you're connected to the right DB? Looks like the issue is server side then..

Comment: @Richard : Yes. The while statement works fine and data shows.

Answer (score 0):

Is your naming right? Example is wrong..

Also, add and `exit;` after `echo json_encode($result);`

[image]

Comment: That's a spelling mistake. Sorry. I tried to display with a while statement and it works. So the json not working properly.

Comment: So you're using `GET`, what do you see when you browse to that URL directly?

Comment: You mean when I type localhost/myProject/industries.php? I see all the records if there is a while statement 
 `while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
     echo $data['Industry'];
 }` with `json_encode($result)` I see `{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null} `. It's a blank page otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for me.

**autocomplete.php**

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="industries">Industries: </label>
  <input id="industries">
</div>

<script>
var validOptions = <?=$json_array?>;
previousValue = "";

$('#industries').autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    source: validOptions
}).keyup(function() {
    var isValid = false;
    for (i in validOptions) {
        if (validOptions[i].toLowerCase().match(this.value.toLowerCase())) {
            isValid = true;
        }
    }
    if (!isValid) {
        this.value = previousValue
    } else {
        previousValue = this.value;
    }
});
</script>
```

**industries.php**

```
//bind to $name
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Industry FROM industries")) {
    $stmt->bind_result($name);
    $OK = $stmt->execute();
}
//put all of the resulting names into a PHP array
$result_array = Array();
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $result_array[] = $name;
}
//convert the PHP array into JSON format, so it works with javascript
$json_array = json_encode($result_array);
```